# How to use DropDownList(ComboList) in MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to use ComboBox in my MVC application but the Html.DropDownListFor is not giving the desired output. My controller code is as follows

```
public class Data_TableController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ListIndex()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "DD",
            Value = "1"
        };
        listSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
        selectList = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "XX",
            Value = "2"
        };
        listSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
        CitiesViewModel citiesViewModel = new CitiesViewModel()
        {
            Cities = listSelectListItems
        };

        return View(citiesViewModel);
    }
  }
```

ListIndex.cshtml code is:

```
    @model MvcDemo.Models.CitiesViewModel
   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "ListIndex";
    }

    <div style=”font-family:Arial”>
    <h2>Index</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new { size = Model.Cities.Count() })
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value=”Submit” />
}
</div>
```

View Model as follows

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedCities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

But the HTML out is as pure list box. Also I like to know, How to add a label here? Attaching the output which I want to be in a combobox. 
[image]

Comment: Try removing new { size = Model.Cities.Count()

Comment: Thanks Paul. Now its showing as combobox. Any idea about adding label and formatting(giving different colors)?

Comment: You cannot format options in the input type `<select>`

Comment: You're playing a little fast and loose with terminology here. A combo box is a control combining a drop down list with an editable text input that can either filter said list or allow free input. There's actually no native HTML control for this; it requires using JavaScript and CSS to fake the look and functionality. However, from your response to Paul, it seems you were actually just looking for a single-select or true-blue dropdown list, not a combo box.

Comment: Thanks Chris. How can i get the selected item? I can use formcollection in the Controller but since DropDownList don't have any name so how can i  refer it in the controller?

Comment: @CrazyC have a look at [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search) which is a great read on how to pass combobox/textbox values to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You are growing the 'display size' of your drop down list by adding:

```
new { size = Model.Cities.Count() }
```

So removing it will make it the default 'display size' of one element.

To add a label, I find the best way is as follows:

In your model, on the property use the DisplayName attribute:

```
[DisplayName("The City:")]
public string Cities { get; set; }
```

Then in your View display it like so:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cities)
```

To give the drop down list / combobox a style do something like the following, i.e. use the new operator:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new { id = "cities", style = "width:320px;color:red;background-color:blue;" })
```

**Edit:**
As jbutler483 pointed out styling could be achieved through the following if you wish to use a css file (however if the style is a one off and is not used elsewhere in the site then inline styles are best):

```
Html.DropDownListFor(..., new { @class = "myclassname" } );
```

Comment: I would agree with all bar the last line, where you're setting inline styles. This can easily be edited to be `@class=...` and then in your css apply the styling options.